# Rails assets pipeline issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I have this piece of  code in my css file

```
<%= asset_path 'dataTables/images/back_enabled.png' %>
```

But it doesn't get executed. It  still remains raw code in browser. What am I missing?

I am in development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this only in files with `erb` extension, so you should give a name to your file like `file.css.erb` or something.

[Ruby on Rails Guides: Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

> 2.2.1 CSS and ERB The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means that if you add an erb extension to a CSS asset (for example,
> application.css.erb), then helpers like asset_path are available in
> your CSS rules:
>
> .class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }